# Meteor: insert only working on client, not persisting in server side database

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript

I am trying to insert a document into an `Activities` collection every time a user executes an action. Here is how I set it up:

Here is my `createActivity` Meteor.method within **collections/activities.coffee**:

```
@Activities = new Mongo.Collection('activities')

Activities.allow
  insert: (userId, activity) ->
    activity.userId == userId

Meteor.methods
  createActivity: (movieId, userId) ->
    # if Meteor.isServer
    #   timer = Stats.createTimer("methods.createActivity")
    Activities.insert {
      docId: movieId
      userId: userId
      action: "favorite"
      collection: "movies"
      createdAt: new Date
    }, (error, results) ->
      console.log error, results
    return
```

Here is where it gets called, in another collection-- **collections/lists.coffee**. It is getting called within another `Meteor.method` which gets called on a click event

```
Meteor.methods
  toggleFavorited: (movieId) ->
    if Meteor.isServer
      timer = Stats.createTimer("methods.toggleFavorited")
    user = Meteor.user()
    return unless user?
    favorited = Meteor.call('toggleInList', user.favorites, movieId)
    if favorited
      Meteor.call 'createActivity', movieId, Meteor.userId()  #LOOK HERE !!!!!
      Movies.update({mid: movieId}, {$inc: favorites: 1})

    else
      Movies.update({mid: movieId}, {$inc: favorites: -1})
    if Meteor.isServer
      timer.stop()
    favorited
```

Here is my publication and subscription:
**server/publications.coffee**

```
Meteor.publish 'activities', ->
  return Activities.find()
```

**lib/router.coffee**

```
Router.configure
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound'
  trackPageView: true
  waitOn: ->
    [
      Meteor.subscribe("activities")
    ]
```

Here is the console log from when I do the user action that triggers the Activties insert method:
[image]

But the document isn't persisted in the database! Why is that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: thanks for sharing your hunch! But I can't see the relevance of that particular issue since I'm not updating any records. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm having the same issue have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to share your folder structure, potentially your method is defined somewhere that meteor thinks is only client-specific code which may explain why it is not getting executed on the server.

My project has the following folders:

```
/client/
/both <-- accessible to both client & server
/server <-- looks like you have this, server only code.
```

If you don't, maybe try moving the method code to a /both/lib folder and see if it gets run on the server.

Comment: My folder structure is
`/client/
/collections/
/server/`
etc... And those Meteor.methods are defined in a file in the collections folder--should be available on both client and server side

Answer (score 0):

How did you define your collection? Did you by any chance pass null as the argument?

```
Activities = new Mongo.Collection(null)
```

will create a local Collection which is not persisted

```
Activities = new Mongo.Collection("activities")
```

will be persisted on the server

Comment: I defined it as `Activities = new Mongo.Collection("activities")`...just added to my question above to see full context

Comment: Hey, I've tried reproducing your issue but it seems to work fine, see http://meteorpad.com/pad/u5EwwijEbkMCge7u5/so%20test (run once, then change something, hit save and see that the server returns the initially inserted document). How are you determining that the document is not persisted? Have you checked the database by using meteor mongo while running your app?

Comment: wow, thanks for reproducing it! yes, I've checked mongo while it's running and the doc isn't persisted. It seems to just be failing silently.